# How do I make my banner periodically refresh to another random banner?

Tags: javascript, php, html, vbulletin

I have a site which shows an ad banner upon page load. I'd like for it to also change while someone is viewing the site, maybe after a few minutes?

This is my current code which displays the initial banner using PHP:

```
$path = '/images/adbanners/'; 
$banners = array( 
array( 'src' => 'look.jpg', 
'href' => 'http://www.example.com/look'), 
array( 'src' => 'see.jpg', 
'href' => 'http://www.example.com/see'), 
array( 'src' => 'horse.jpg',
'href' => 'http://www.example.com'), 
array( 'src' => 'scg.png', 
'href' => 'https://www.example.com/scg/'), 
array( 'src' => 'karen.png', 
'href' => 'http://www.example.com/'karen), 
); 

$rnd = mt_rand(0,count($banners)-1); // Pick a random array index.  They start with 0, so you have to -1. 
$href = $banners[$rnd]['href'];  // Link HREF 
$src = $path.$banners[$rnd]['src']; // Image source 
$randombanner = '<a href="'.$href.'" target="_blank" alt="example.com Sponsor!" title="example.com Sponsor!"><img border="0" src="'.$src.'" /></a>'; 
vB_Template::preRegister('navbar', array('randombanner' => $randombanner));
```

I have an idea that this could be accomplished using JavaScript but don't know where to start. I'd rather not add a library such as jQuery to the site, as it doesn't already use it for anything.

Comment: Pretty similar looking code in JS with something like `setInterval` thrown in would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest sending a list of other ads as JSON, and then using JS to swap it. You could do that with a `setInterval`. This is a little bit trickier without jQuery, do you have any other libraries on the site?

For the PHP, add

```
$ads_json=json_encode($banners);
```

underneath where you declare the $banners array.

Change your banner element to have an ID so we can access it via JS easily.

```
$randombanner = '<a id="sponsor_banner" href="'.$href.'" target="_blank" alt="example.com Sponsor!" title="example.com Sponsor!"><img border="0" src="'.$src.'" /></a>';
```

Then add to the $randombanner html...

```
<script>
    var ads='.$ads_json.';
    function swap_ad(){
        var ad_el=document.getElementById("sponsor_banner");
        var img=ad_el.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
        var random_ad=ads[Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length)];
        ad_el.href=random_ad["href"];
        img.src='.$path.'random_ad["src"];
        };
    window.setInterval(swap_ad,90000000);
</script>
```

It would be nice to put the script in the head. Putting it by the element will work though, not sure about the limitations of vBulletin.

Comment: hmm it seems like you and I posted almost *exactly* the same answer... funny :P

Comment: @joetje590 probably because that's the way it's done!

Comment: I would recommend not using `Element.children` though, especially not for fundamental features such as advertisements. According to [MDN's browser support list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode.children#Browser_compatibility), IE (who else) doesn't support this until version 9. The browser support for `Element.getElementsById('img')` is [much higher](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName#Browser_Compatibility).

Comment: @joeytje50 golly, I'm not up on my DOM methods, I see. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Between your answer and Joey's answer I figured it out. I would upvote you if I had enough rep. Thank you for your help!!

Comment: @joeytje50 based on MDN and quirksmode, looks like ie<9 do support that method. It's just that they also count comment and empty text nodes.

Comment: @JAL ah okay, so basically it won't return errors, but it won't work like it does in other browsers either.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to load a new iframe every 5 minutes, just use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval):

```
window.adverts = [
    {src:'look.jpg', href:'http://www.example.com/look'},
    {src:'see.jpg', href:'http://www.example.com/see'},
    //etc
];
setInterval(function() {
    var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * adverts.length);
    var banner = document.getElementById('bannerId');
    banner.getElementByTagName('img')[0].src = adverts[rnd].src;
    banner.href = adverts[rnd].href;
}, 5 * 60 * 1000);
```

This will require you to add `id="bannerId"` to your banner's surrounding `<a>` tag. You can also change the `'bannerId'` in the script to any other id if you like, and then add another id to your banner.

That will store all the adverts' image sources and anchor urls in a global object `adverts` and then run the code to switch to another random advert every 5 minutes. You just need to put this script within a [`<script>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/script) tag on your html page. You can instead of manually adding the urls also just inject the urls via PHP, by instead something like this to define the global `adverts` variable:

```
window.adverts = [
    <?php
        echo json_encode($banners)
    ?>
];
```

That automatically puts all the contents from your `$banners` variable into the JavaScript `adverts` variable.

Comment: Between your answer and JAL's answer I figured it out. I would upvote you if I had enough rep. Thank you for your help!!

Comment: No problem! By the way, as the asker you can mark the one answer (the one you liked best) as accepted, via the checkmark button below the points.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server-side language whose work is done when your page loads.  However, there are some solid tutorials available from sites like htmlgoodies which will help you with what you're looking for.

Look at this tutorial here: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3881826

Answer (score 0):

use a timeout. Documentation for a time is at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout

Basically you set a timeout function to call you function that changes the banner after a set number of milliseconds.

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    // call to function to rotate or change banner
}, ms);
```

Does this help? Or are you looking for the full example in JS.

Comment: I looked at the docs for set timeout...won't that just change it one time?

Comment: @Misha Dough probably meant to refer to `setInterval` which is the repeating version of `setTimeout`. You can check my answer or JAL's to see a more detailed answer including the `setInterval`.

Comment: Yeah good catch, my bad I did mean to put setInterval but I got typing before I thought about it I guess. It is window.setInterval to set a interval timer. setTimeout only fires once. Good looking out guys.